# Erro de sintaxe ao utilizar .val() em um JSON

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando checar um valor no JSON para saber se é `null` num valor que contém um link de imagem. Mas quando existe um link retorna um erro:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

Estou usando usando corretamente?

```
var cardapiojson = "https://api.sheety.co/1a888dce-0342-4f9a-9bb6-b0e132d4b33f";

    $.getJSON(cardapiojson, function(data) {
    $(data).each( function (index) {
      var itemImage =  data[index]['img'];

      console.log($(itemImage).val());
```

Sei que o erro está no `.val()` porque quando comento o `console.log($(itemImage).val());` o site monta normalmente.

Comment: E o que esperava obter com `$(itemImage).val()`?

Comment: itemImage é o valor e não um elemento, por isso o erro. basta fazer console.log(itemImage);

Comment: Para verificar se é null, basta fazer `if(!itemImage){ // é null }`

Comment: Era isso mesmo @Sam. Obrigado pela ajuda. Procurei em outros lugares e todos mandavam usar .val() para saber se era null.

Comment: .val() é pra pegar valor de elementos de formulário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Estou usando corretamente?**
>
> Não.

---

O método [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) realiza a leitura do arquivo JSON e o transforma em objeto ou matriz (array) dependendo da estrutura do arquivo, que no seu caso é uma matriz de objetos.

Então para analisar cada objeto dessa matriz você precisa de uma iteração. Para a iteração você está utilizando o método [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), que itera sobre um objeto JQuery (`$(data)`).

E para acessar a propriedade **img** do objeto iterado, está sendo utilizado o `this` que neste caso está fazendo referência ao objeto iterado.

```js
$(function() {

  var cardapioJson = "https://api.sheety.co/1a888dce-0342-4f9a-9bb6-b0e132d4b33f";

  $.getJSON(cardapioJson, function(data) {
    $(data).each(function(index) {
      if (!this.img) {
        //Comportamento para quando a propriedade img for nula
        console.log('null');
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Conforme o exemplo no site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://api.sheety.co/uk-theme-parks', function(data) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#item-template').html())
        $('#items').html(template(data)) //joga o resultado dentro da tag #items
    })
})
```

...

```
<div id="items">Loading theme parks...</div>
```

O #items é um elemento html, que está recebendo o resultado dentro dele.

Fonte: https://sheety.co/

Comment: `if(!itemImage){ // é null }` era só isso que eu precisava. Mas obrigado pela resposta, Fernando!